# semantic-release: trigger chore(release) only on finished pipeline

Tags: gitlab-ci, semantic-release

I'm (mis)using semantic-release when building a C++ application in a GitLab CI.

My config is quite minimal
.releaserc.json

```
{
  "branches": ["main", "develop"],
  "plugins": [
    "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
    "@semantic-release/gitlab",
    "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
    [
      "@semantic-release/changelog",
      {
        "changelogFile": "public/CHANGELOG.md"
      }
    ],
    [
      "@semantic-release/git",
      {
        "assets": ["public/CHANGELOG.md"]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

In the GitLab Ci, I have a couple of stages

Versioning -> Build -> Test -> Deploy

Versioning

```
version:
  tags:
    - macOS
  stage: version
  script:
    - export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
  
    # Configure semantic-release
    - npm install
    - npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline
    - |
      {
        echo "@${CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE}:registry=${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/"
        echo "${CI_API_V4_URL#https?}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/:_authToken=\${CI_JOB_TOKEN}"
      } | tee -a .npmrc

    - npm run semantic-release 
    - VERSION=$(grep -i -ow '\d\.\d\.\d' public/CHANGELOG.md | head -1) 
    - echo $VERSION > public/VERSION.txt
    - echo $VERSION

  artifacts:
   name: "Changelog"
   paths:
     - public/*
```

*Build* relies on the Artifacts of *Versioning*, because it needs to add the current version to cmake. And yes, I'm grepping the version number from the change log, don't judge me :D

Works fine, but semantic-release is creating the tag right in the version stage. This could lead to problems, if the pipeline fails. Re-running a failed pipeline should result in an error "semantic-release: tag already exists".

is there any way to create the tag in a seperate stage at the very end, only if the rest of the pipeline succeeded?

Thanks!